# Create Test Project with Load Test Enabled in .NET Framework 4.5

Tags: c#, load-testing

I want to do Load Testing for my Http Connection and Tcp Connection and for that I want to create test project, but i am not able to find test project template which allows me Load Test operation on my test method. I am using Visual Studio 2013 and .NET framework 4.5, Is this feature not available in newer version?

Please suggest how can i do Load testing of above connection with actual requests?

Where can i find above template in newer version of .NET Framework and visual studio ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which SKU of Visual Studio are you using? Is it Visual Studio Ultimate? You need to have VS Ultimate to author Load Tests. Once you open VS -> File -> New Project -> Test -> Web Performance And Load Test Project.

Did this answer your question?

Thanks

Comment: I found the answer already, as exactly suggested by you. thanks !!